# javafx scenebuilder scrollpane

Tags: java, javafx

I am using Gluon SceneBuilder to build a JavaFX application and want to use the scrollbar on the scroll pane to scroll the content.

I have a TableView with two table columns on the scroll pane. When I drag the thumb, instead of scrolling the content, the scroll bar is scrolling the whole table view. So when I drag the thumb to the bottom, it does not show the remaining content. I want to keep the headers fixed, and only the content is scrollable. How can I make it work?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: TableView has its own scrollbar. Why put it in a scrollpane?

Comment: I got it. I am new to JavaFX and seems like I did an unnecessary wrapping. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @YichaoQin could you mark my answer as correct. It will help others to identify the question with answer.

Answer (score 4):

JavaFX TableView have a scrollbar by default. When your table records exceeded than the table's height or width, it will generate the Scrollbar automatically.